# Is there an issue with android wrt Orientation

Tags: android, orientation, android-orientation

It seems like there is an issue with orientation change in android atleast on the device. When i navigate to settings - apps - running and i select - Show cached processes and then flip the orientation it changes back to - show running processes. I have a use-case in my app where-in i take the device orientation to display some options but that doesnt seem to be getting honored. Any suggestions on this and might this be because of the sample flow that i have mentioned ?
I have used this to get the orientation :

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

and this for rotation :

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int rotation = display.getRotation();
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If there was a bug with android in the mentioned flow.

Answer (score 1):

What you are using is correct, I use the combo of two

```
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();
```

Now use them to determine the correct orientation

```
    if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90) {
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                // Portrait 
            }
            else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                // Landscape
            }
        }
        else if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                //Mainly for tablets
            }
            else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
               //Mainly for tablets
            }
        }
```